# Switching font-face Between Languages

Tags: css, font-face, typography

I have a `@font-face` in use. It's a Hebrew font by definition. When I switch to English in mid sentence (which is sometimes necessary) I get something which is entirely unconnected to the original font I'm using.

It seems, as the browser recognizes the font, the rule stops there, i.e.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: MySans, sans-serif;
}
```

It recognizes `MySans`, which is sans-serif, but for latin letters it would use a default, Times New Roman or something, which is serif, and not fall back to the `sans-serif` I gave him.

Is there a way to define this to work conveniently? `<span>`-ing every English insert is not convenient, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Would defining multiple fonts in the `font-family` property help at all? When the first font isn't available, it falls back on the next font, and so on until it either finds one that works or goes to the default.

Try something like:

```
font-family: MySans, Arial, Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
```

and let me know if that works!